# NotesSQL Driver not working in Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ibm-domino

I'm trying to install the NotesSQL Driver on a Server 2008 machine in order to run Reports in Report Server against a Lotus/Domino database but I can't get it to work at all. I downloaded the latest version 8.5 but it doesn't even show up in the ODBC window.

Comment: Well I think one problem is that I need to have notes installed which I did not realize. Why can't the driver just work on it's own?

Comment: Not really a solution, but if you need to do a lot of Notes to SQL data transfer (vica versa) you might prefer to buy a package called Notrix. It requires a Domino server to host the applicationm, but doesn't require a Notes client on the SQL Server. You also need the latest SQL Server ODBC driver as SQL Server 2000's driver memory leaks with the latest version of Notrix. It beats LEI and NotesSQL hands down for functionality.

Answer (score 1):

> The NotesSQL driver is a 32-bit ODBC driver, so you have to register
>   it as such
>
> ODBC on running on a 64-bit-based operating system has two sets of
>   system DSN settings stored in the Windows Registry. 32-bit client
>   applications use the 32-bit settings. 64-bit applications use the
>   64-bit settings.
>
> If you run "%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe", you modify the 32-bit
>   settings. If you run "%SystemRoot%\system32\odbcad32.exe", you modify
>   the 64-bit settings (this is the one run from the Control Panel -->
>   Administrative Tools --> Data Sources --> ODBC).
>
> You must register the System DSN for the ODBC32 drivers with
>   SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe.

source: [Keysolutions](http://www.keysolutions.com/NotesFAQ/cannotessql.html)

Comment: I tried opening the odbcad32.exe in the SysWOW directory but I will try modifying the the registry and see if that works. Thanks

Comment: also you more then likely will need to run the syswow odbcad32.exe as admin